# start and end time of 200 log files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have around 200 directories.  Each directory contains only one log file.
first line of log file specifies the time the particular job start and last line the job end time.

I can export the directory names to a CSV file.  I need help with capturing start and end time from the log file inside of each directory.

please share command/loop.  Here is an example.

```
Direcotry PS-PR-9928883838383 
log name PS-PR-9928883838383.log
```

within the log, there will timestamp of when it started and the last timestamp.

```
  2019-08-29::22:59:13 INFO com.bns.csm.####.####AppHandlerImpl:868 [pool-1-thread-5] #### = /bns/csm/ac_data/workdir/MsgService/####/Apps/####/working/PS-PR-20190829225849147/priceReq_@@@@_PS-PR-20190829225849147_20190830.csv completion confirmation is known by below line 2019-08-29::22:59:22 INFO com.bns.csm.####24 [pool-87-thread-1] THREAD for ### extract with output location = /bns/csm/ac_data/workdir/MsgService/####/Apps/@@@@/working/PS-PR-20190829225849147/priceResponse_@@@@_PS-PR-20190829225849147_20190830.txt: End. –
```

Comment: can u share those two lines of a file?

Comment: 2019-08-29::22:59:13 INFO com.bns.csm.####.####AppHandlerImpl:868 [pool-1-thread-5] #### = /bns/csm/ac_data/workdir/MsgService/####/Apps/####/working/PS-PR-20190829225849147/priceReq_@@@@_PS-PR-20190829225849147_20190830.csv

completion confirmation is known by below line
2019-08-29::22:59:22 INFO com.bns.csm.####24 [pool-87-thread-1] THREAD for ### extract with output location = /bns/csm/ac_data/workdir/MsgService/####/Apps/@@@@/working/PS-PR-20190829225849147/priceResponse_@@@@_PS-PR-20190829225849147_20190830.txt: End.

Comment: to add, the directory name is also created with etension of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS; so that would be the start time.  ENd time would have to be fetched from log file.

Comment: please add your sample log file data to your Question.  It's no use in a comment.

Comment: that can't be the actual data because it's only one line, not the two that were mentioned. it looks like you've just copy-pasted the comment. please copy and paste directly from your terminal, and format it as code.   it's important to have the actual data in the same format as on your machine because details like linefeeds and spaces matter.

Comment: sure. will do.  newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
find . -type f -name 'PS-PR-*.log' -exec awk '
  NR==1 { printf "%s,%s,", FILENAME, $1};
  $NF == "End." {print $1}' {} +
```

You haven't posted your log data yet, so i'm unsure if the `–` that appears to be on the end of the `End.` line is actually there or if it is some copy and paste artifact.  The above assumes it isn't there.

If it **is** really there, then the `End.` is in the 2nd last field, not the last.  So use:

```
$(NF-1) == "End." {print $1}
```

instead.